# Reinstall Raspbian without wiping SD card

Tags: cron

I recently upgraded my pi3 using `apt`. After a number of packages were upgraded, `cron` stopped working. Instead of executing its jobs, `cron` now drops a message in /var/log/daemon.log:

Oct 29 19:40:01 cron[300]: Failure setting user credentials

I get a similar message in `$>service cron status`.

After googling the error messages it seems to be related to `pam krb5` (libpam-systemd was indeed one of the packages that was upgraded). However I can't find a fix, and my raspberry pi is pretty much useless without `cron`.

So my question is this: "Is there a way to reinstall the Raspbian packages from some stable version without wiping the entire SD card?" I've wondered if rolling back `libpam-systemd` to a previous version might resolve the issue, and if so, how would I do that?

I have a bunch of scripts and software running, and a lot of custom configurations, so I'd like to avoid starting from scratch with a clean installation.

Comment: Of course you could also restore the last of your regular backups...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that a downgrade of only `libpam-systemd` will work. It is deep integrated in the system and will not fit with the other updated packages. If you try to also downgrade the depended packages you will get a mixed up system. I don't believe that you can control it. You can look if you find a previous version with:

```
rpi ~$ apt-cache showpkg libpam-systemd
```

Here you can also see dependencies. If there is an older version you can try to install it. But I would strongly recommend to do first a dry run for example with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt --dry-run install libpam-systemd=232-25+deb9u4
```

But if you ask me I would look forward instead of looking backwards. It seems to be easier to fix the failure setting user credentials. If its only with cron you may consider to use the [anternative systemd.timer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers).

Comment: Thanks @Ingo. I didn't know about systems timers. It works perfectly although it is a bit unsatisfying to run a system with a broken cron daemon. But never mind, it is better than reinstalling from scratch.